# Two age variables in regression

Tags: r, regression

I am performing an hierarchical regression. One of the binary factor variables is if someone is 65 or older (1) or if they are  younger than 65 (0). However, I am also applying stratification for age (and gender).

I received feedback with the question why I did this. So now I am questioning my own approach... Is it redundant in your opinion to have two age variables, one normal variable and one in stratification, in my analysis?

An example of my strata information:

> strata[1:5,2:7]

```
      agegrp_1   agegrp_2  agegrp_3  agegrp_4   agegrp_5   agegrp_6
[1,] 0.3408521 0.10025063 0.1378446 0.2731830 0.13784461 0.01002506
[2,] 0.3471074 0.23966942 0.1157025 0.1900826 0.10743802 0.00000000
[3,] 0.3646209 0.13357401 0.1516245 0.2527076 0.09747292 0.00000000
[4,] 0.3934426 0.26229508 0.1147541 0.2131148 0.01639344 0.00000000
[5,] 0.2844828 0.08189655 0.1724138 0.3146552 0.13362069 0.01293103
```

Where I make use of six age ranges (15-30, 31-45, 46-60, 61-75, 76-90 and 91-105).

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What does your stratification information look like?

Comment: I have edited my post with the strata information

Answer (score 0):

Both the binary variable and the stratification are ways of binning the same underlying, continuous variable into a different number of differently sized bins. Though they reflect the same type of information, the way you choose them does not make them completely redundant (though you could have asked for both in one question in your questionnaire instead). Combining both variables, the resulting bins are simply 15-30, 31-45, 46-60, **61-65, 66-75**, 76-90 and 91-105. If you would have chosen your stratification to have a bin end and another one start at age of 65 instead, the information would in fact have been completely redundant.

BTW: for most problems I could imagine, merging this information into one variable before handing it to models is most likely reasonable - as most models will be able to handle this information correctly this way.